# simple XML deserialization #2

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, rdf

I am learning XML serialization behaviours and limitations. I have simple XML file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"   xmlns:cim="http://iec.ch/TC57/2001/CIM-schema-cim10#">
  <cim:BaseVoltage rdf:ID="BaseVoltage_01">
    <cim:BaseVoltage.nominalVoltage>42</cim:BaseVoltage.nominalVoltage>
  </cim:BaseVoltage>
</rdf:RDF>
```

c# Code :

```
public class Voltage
{
    public double value;
    public String units;

    public Voltage() 
    { 
    }
}

public class BaseVoltage 
{
    private Voltage volt; 

    public BaseVoltage()
    {
        volt = new Voltage();
        ConductingEquipment = new ConductingEquipment[10];
        VoltageLevel = new VoltageLevel[10];
    }

   [XmlElement("BaseVoltage.nominalVoltage")]
    public Voltage NominalVoltage
    {
        get { return volt; }
        set { volt = value; }
    }   
}
```

when i deserialize xml file, my c# objects shows

```
baseVoltage.NominalVoltage.value = 0.0
```

I am expecting

```
baseVoltage.NominalVoltage.value = 42.
```

XML serialization is puzzling for me. 
in this case why i am not getting value 42??

Comment: You haven't specified namespaces for any of your elements.

Comment: `I have simple XML file like below` it isn't as simple as you think ,with two namespaces. I would start learning with more simpler ones.

Comment: You need to set the NamespaceManager for the `cim:` namespace.

Comment: also `rdf:` for `ID` attribute..